# (Logic behind) Geometric construction for imaginary roots of quadratic.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, inversive-geometry

In the question on this site [Geometric derivation of the quadratic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588479/geometric-derivation-of-the-quadratic-equation/2119961#2119961)

there are geometric constructions for real roots of a quadratic. As a follow-up
I found the construction below for imaginary roots, which I understand from the
paper referenced within the diagram, has some connection to inversion in the
Euclidean plane.

While I understand how to work through the construction and demonstrate its
validity, I would appreciate anyone's insights into how this connects with
inversive geometry (or, if that is a mistaken reference, what the intuitive
raison d'etre for this might be!).

[image]